# Extract Entire array object from json body

Tags: javascript, postman

Need to extract entire `database_schema_detail` object from the below json body for postman.Any suggestion?

Json Body

```
    "created_operator": "0",
    "database": "postgres",
    "database_schema_detail": {
      "accounts": [
        "employer_id",
        "id",
        "role_id"
      ],
      "awsdms_ddl_audit": [
        "c_ddlqry",
        "c_key",
        "c_name",
        "c_oid",
        "c_schema",
        "c_tag",
        "c_time",
        "c_txn",
        "c_user"
      ],
      "new_accounts": [
        "employer_id",
        "id",
        "role_id"
      ]
    },
    "dms_endpoint_id": "test0700362021-10-07t13-19-36-331734",
    "engine": "postgresql",
    "engine_display_name": "PostgreSQL",
```

Answer (score 1):

Parse the JSON and access the property:

```
let responseBody = JSON.parse(body);
console.log(responseBody.database_schema_detail);
```

Comment: Thanks Tushar Shahi for your response..could you help to extract the entire elements of database_schema_detail , my objective is to store the entire o/p for database_schema_detail in a variable so that i can pass it as a parameter to the request body. 



My Code:
pm.test('Validate Schema',function(){
   var jsonData=pm.response.json();
    pm.environment.set('dbSchemaDetails',jsonData.data.database_schema_detail);
   console.log(jsonData.data.database_schema_detail);
})
Here i am able to log the output ,but unable to store it into "dbSchemaDetails"

Appreciate your help..

Comment: Hi Tushar,
Was able to solve the issue using JSON.stringify...Thanks for the assist